# Chrome extension - read current page source

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get my chrome extension to read the current page source & detect current url, so for example..

If i was to navigate to

```
https://www.google.com
```

and page source contains

```
google
```

i want my extension to pop an alert with specified text..

I need to know how to add permissions to manifest.json & also detect the current url + read page source.

Comment: You can declare a content script in manifest.json using include_globs as shown in [Chrome extension: Run on all google domains and a specific page](//stackoverflow.com/a/18616735) and inside the content script `alert('your text')`.

Comment: @wOxxOm rather than producing a js alert, is it possible to open my default_popup?

Comment: There's an undocumented method available inside [event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages): `chrome.browserAction.openPopup(() => {})`, which you can combine with declarativeContent API or webNavigation API. I'm not interested in describing the entire solution so you can study the mentioned APIs yourself using the documentaiton and [samples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples).

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the hostname of the current tab like this:

```
function getTab(callback) {
  chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    lastFocusedWindow: true
  }, (res) => {
    var tab = new URL(res[0].url);
    callback(tab.hostname);
  });
};

getTab((hostname) => console.log(hostname))
```

and you'll need to set permissions in the manifest file to:

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
  ]
```